# Using Mojo Event Loop for a long-running script processing huge text files?

Tags: perl, fork, mojolicious

I have a script implemented as a Mojo::Command.
It reads a huge text file and extracts data from it. The file contains simple tab separated (C/TSV) records. One record per line.
How can  I use the Mojo Event loop to  store those records in small files - one file per record - so my script does not wait for each record to be stored but continues to the next record.

Here is a stripped down example:

```
package My::task;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Command';
 #in My::task::run
#use Text::CSV to open and read the file
while (!$csv->eof()) {
  my $row = $csv->getline($fh)
  do_something_time_consuming_and_store_the_record_somewhere($row)
 }
```

I was thinking Mojo Event Loop can be used and avoid forking/threading.
I used successfully previously [Parallel::Forker](https://metacpan.org/module/Parallel%3a%3aForker), but I was thinking Mojo has what to offer to speedup the execution.
Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the nature of do_something_time_consuming.  If that is something that has your process CPU-busy, then you're looking for parallelism, which an event loop doesn't try to give you.  In that event you might want to feed each row to redis (via mojo::redis) and have worker processes consume, process, store each record.  Then throughput is down to how many parallel workers you can run.

On the other hand, if do_something_time_consuming involves a lot of waiting, eg post to a web service and wait for results, then an event loop (incl mojo's) can be a big win, and handle the concurrency that you want.  It's hard to guess which of the non-blocking UserAgent examples is closest to your scenario, since you're short on detail.  The gist is to create a callback that does what you want (eg store_the_record_somewhere) when it gets a response back from the remote service.

Comment: do_something...($row) is complicated :). It may happen to connect to a mysql database or not depending on what it finds in the record. It also can be CPU intensive on guessing things from the record it self etc. This is why I abstracted it away. 
But supposedly I want not to wait for the IO part to store/dump the record at least and/or not waiting for mysql to respond, how should i proceed?

Comment: I was thinking also to split the command in a server and client side parts using hypnotoad even maybe... well also not sure how :)...

Comment: So you have a combination :o)  I'm having lots of win using IOLoop with async calls through DBD::mysql.  But since you have a combination, you really want to go with mojo::redis and an army of resque workers.  (diegok on #mojo is our resident expert)